# what version of an npm package is installed?

Tags: npm, expo

While preparing an app for release to the Google Play Store I discovered it was necessary to upgrade the Expo SDK in the project in order to successfully upload the app bundle (to target at least API level 29).  Once the Expo SDK was upgraded to 39.0.0 the upload worked fine.  However, while upgrading the Expo SDK a message in the terminal said

> The following packages were not updated.  You should check the READMEs
> for those repositories to determine what version is compatible with
> your new set of packages:
> expo-linking

I couldn't tell from the README which expo-linking version should be used with Expo SDK 39.0.0.

After the Expo SDK upgrade, package.json shows this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^39.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~1.0.1",
```

Since the terminal message said expo-linking was not updated I *presume* package.json.dependencies.expo-linking didn't change either.

Running `npm view expo-linking versions --json` reveals these versions exist:

```
[
  "1.0.0-beta.1",
  "1.0.0",
  "1.0.1",
  "1.0.2",
  "1.0.3",
  "1.0.4"
]
```

Two questions:

1. How/where can the installed version of expo-linking be found?
2. I figured I'd install the latest version since the latest version of the Expo SDK is now installed for this project.  Could that cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm writing this all without much knowledge about expo itself so apologies in advance if this is not useful.)

Assuming your dependencies were installed in a `node_modules` directory, `npm ls expo-linking` should reveal the installed version (or versions if your dependencies are using more than one).

```
$ npm ls expo-linking           
/Users/foo/projects/my-cool-project
└── expo-linking@1.0.4 
$
```

As for whether the latest version will cause problems: The latest version of `expo-linking` was published 2 months ago (at the time of this writing) and the package gets a fair amount of downloads. (According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-linking at the time of this writing, the package gets downloaded around 80000 times a week.) So if it is causing problems, there's a good chance someone would have reported it by now in the issue tracker at https://github.com/expo/expo/issues. You can perhaps do some searches there to get an idea if others are experiencing any of the problems you are concerned about.

Comment: In the project directory for this app the output of that command is showing `UNMET DEPENDENCY expo-linking@1.0.1`.  So that must mean expo-linking version 1.0.1 is installed...?  I did not do an `npm install` after doing the Expo SDK updates - would that be the cause of the unmet dependency?  I don't have much experience with npm packages, as you can probably tell.

Comment: Yes, dependencies are installed in a `node_modules` directory within the app's project directory.

Comment: From the project directory, does `node -p 'require.resolve("expo-linking")'` report a "Cannot find module" error or does it report a path name?

Comment: Here is the result of that command: `/home/knot22/Documents/myapp/node_modules/expo-linking/build/Linking.js`.  It appears to be a path name rather than an error.

Comment: Is `/home/knot22/Documents/myapp` your project directory/cwd? What happens with `grep version /home/knot22/Documents/myapp/node_modules/expo-linking/package.json`?

Comment: Yes, `/home/knot22/Documents/myapp` is my project directory and that was the location from which I executed the `node -p 'require.resolve("expo-linking")'` command.  When the `grep version /home/knot22/Documents/myapp/node_modules/expo-linking/package.json` command is executed from the project directory it returns `"version": "1.0.4"`.

Comment: OK, so you have expo-linking@1.0.4 installed in your node_modules, but `npm ls` is reporting that it is an unmet dependency. The [package.json for expo sdk 39.0.1](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/36f0c3f1b19311be734f616e091ab6e123c4d23f/packages/expo/package.json) says it needs expo-linking 1.0.4 as does [the package.json for 39.0.0](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/2196cebae55bda181ccceadec809942f51ee9e39/packages/expo/package.json). Something unusual is going on, but I'm not sure what it is. Would love to dig in to it, but I don't think a comment thread is going to get us there quickly...

Comment: ...and I don't know a whole lot about Expo, so maybe it's something trivial that someone more knowledgable would know about right away.